# Generate unique pairs from list several times without duplicates

Tags: python, list

After reading many threads here I finally have my first own question.
I want to write a script in python that takes a file with names and team codes as input and stores them in a list.
Then the program is supposed to find random pairs of those people, but team mates shouldn’t be in a pair. Whenever a pair is found with random.choice the two people should be pop of the list.
So far so easy. But now i want to repeat this process every month and there shouldn’t be repeated pairs…

My idea was to store all past combinations  in another file and every time a new match is found it first will check in the list if there already has been this pair in the past.

Are there any better ways to do that ?

Would love to get your ideas on that!

Comment: first, provide a [mre], second, have you looked at the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module?

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable solution.

Comment: thank you! Yes i had a Look at the combinations functions. But then I have all possible combinations and I wasn’t able to figure out how I then can get random pairs from them which cover all my people from the input list at the end.

Comment: @user15455735 you can then use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Comment: But don’t I have the problem that I can have one person in more than one randomly selected pair ? Because the masterlist then includes all available combinations, when i then use random.seed with the amount of people in my input list/2 I will not get pairs which include all of my participants.. or what am I missing here …

Comment: could you please provide a sample of the file that contains players and teams?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomize it, you are going to need a way to store previous pairs. Either a file, or a database. It sounds like it is going to be a pretty simple program, so a json file might make the most sense for storage.

Unless I'm missing something (which I often do), I believe checking it against your storage will be the only way to determine if a random pair has been selected before.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! 
Yes I thought of saving the old combinations in a file and then check against them!

Comment: A common way of avoiding duplicates is to create a temporary `set` containing the ones already encountered and checking new candidates for membership before adding them.